# Why there is a resistor connected between terminal and the ground?

Tags: operational-amplifier, basic

Why a resistor is connected between non inverting terminal and ground?[image]

Comment: The resistor to ground will have the same input bias current in it as the other input causes in its input resistors. Then the offset voltages cancel and will not be amplified.